# Autosys Job running only once after starting time even when predecessors are sucess

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

1. I have a case where I want the job to run from Day 1 to Day 5 of a
   month and when it's predecessor is success.
2. But what's happening
   is the job runs once a day after start time even when predecessor
   run multiple times through the day( I want my job to also refresh as
   many times as predecessor do)

```
Job A 
date_conditions: 1
run_calendar: D1_D5       
start_times: "00:00"
condition: s(Job B)
```

I tried removing start_time but with calendar it takes a default start time of "00:00" anyway and gets scheduled for next day after first run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want Job A to run only on Days 1-5, but every time Job B runs on those days.

You could update your script logic for Job A so that it only truly runs on Day 1 to Day 5 (the rest of the month would be some kind of dummy script), then change the dependency so it's just dependent on Job B.

If you want to use the scheduler, recommend you clone Job B and schedule that to run on Days 1-5. Then change Job A to be dependent on the Job B clone.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @vkeeWork. I did evaluate the first option of checking dates in the script but that was getting complicated as calendar was taking US holidays as well. Any idea how/if we can access the calendar jil in our script? Also with the Job B clone having the calendar, wouldn't it throw the same issue of now the clone job not running multiple times as needed?

Comment: You can't refer to an AutoSys calendar in your JIL actually.

If the Job B clone only runs on your AutoSys calendar for days 1-5, and Job A is only dependent on Job B clone (no other run conditions like date, time), Job A should run whenever Job B clone runs. Give it a go in your lower environment, and see how it goes.